# How Do I read a CSV containing columns that are not in the Class you are reading into with .NET using CsvContext.Read<T>()?

Tags: c#, .net, csv, linqtocsv

I have a Business Object class containing private fields which are populated in the constructor

```
private int mP_Id;
private int mP_MerchantId;
private int mP_ProductId;
private decimal mP_Price;
private int mP_StockCount;
private string mP_Condition;
private bool mP_Published;
private int? mP_ConditionId;
private string mP_URL;
private string mP_CurrencyCode;
private DateTime? mP_DateUpdated;
private bool mP_Active;
private string mP_MerchantProductIdentifier;
private int? mP_ApiProductFoundId;
```

I have a CSV file that contains these columns but also has additional columns that will be used in the business logic to retrieve the correct mP_ProductId from another database table.

If I use `CsvContext.Read<T>()` it throws an exception telling me that the extra columns are not found in my Business Object.

```
                var cc = new CsvContext();
                var relationships = cc.Read<MerchantProductRelBO>(file.FilePath, inputFileDescription);
```

I tried to place these extra fields and overload the constructor in the MerchantProductRelBO.custom.cs but it still didn't use the overloaded constructor and threw the same exception.  I can't do this in the MerchantProductRelBO.cs because the file gets overwritten anytime the database structure changes.

Do I just need to abandon the LinqToCsv library and write a manual parser to read from the CSV or is there a way to get it to parse the extra-BO columns without throwing an exception?

Comment: Extend the class and add your own fields, then use that. Assuming the BO class isn't marked final/sealed...if it is, use composition instead.

Comment: It really helps if you say where `CsvContext.Read<T>()` comes from and / or what LinqToCsv library you are using exactly.

Comment: Assuming you are using [LinqToCsv](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqToCsv/) (which is quite old), the documentation says you can create a `CsvFileDescription` with the property `IgnoreUnknownColumns` set to `true` and pass it as the second parameter.

Comment: [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) seems like a nice new library.